# append list B to list A and deleting list B elements for new elements python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I am trying to append data from list B to list A to create list within a list , using listA.append(listB) is not working , i am newbie to python is there anything extra needed to be added?

here is the sample code

```
`from random import randint
 def call():
     c=0
     a=[]
     b=[]
     while (c != 10):
        b.append(randint(0,9))
        print b
        a.append(b)
        print a
        del b[:]
        c=c+1

 for i in range(2):
    call()`
```

here is the output

```
`[7]
 [[7]]
 [3]
 [[3], [3]]
 [3]
 [[3], [3], [3]]
 [8]
 [[8], [8], [8], [8]]
 [0]
 [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
 [7]
 [[7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7]]
 [3]
 [[3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
 [9]
 [[9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9]]
 [2]
 [[2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
 [1]
 [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
 [8]
 [[8]]
 [0]
 [[0], [0]]
 [0]
 [[0], [0], [0]]
 [6]
 [[6], [6], [6], [6]]
 [2]
 [[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
 [7]
 [[7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7]]
 [9]
 [[9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9]]
 [7]
 [[7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7]]
 [6]
 [[6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6]]
 [1]
 [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]`
```

i do not understand why is this happening?

Comment: What is the desired output? Actually, you have lists within your list.

Comment: the desired out put is ``[7]
 [[7]]
 [3]
 [[3], [7]]
 [3]
 [[3], [3], [7]]
 [8]
 [[8], [3], [3], [7]]
 [0]
 [[0],[8], [3], [3], [7]]
 [7]
 [[7],[0],[8], [3], [3], [7]]
`

Comment: @GeminiKeith i want to append all in the current instance of listB to listA. i had tried `listA = listA + listB` but this is giving me the `[0,1]` type of listA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't appending the *contents* of `b`, you're appending `b` itself. You need to rebind `b` in the loop rather than just emptying the previous contents.

```
 ...
print a
b = []
c=c+1
```

Answer (score 1):

You always append the **same** list object `b` to your list. This means, your list `a` will contain 10 times the **same** list object `b`.

Changed to the contents of `b` are now reflected to all items in `a` and this is what you are wondering about.

The following code does what you intend to do.

```
from random import randint

def call():
    c=0
    a=[]
    while (c != 10):
        b = [] # a new list for each iteration!
        b.append(randint(0,9))
        print b
        a.append(b)
        print a
        c=c+1

for i in range(2):
    call()`
```

Comment: thanks , +1 for the explaination. :) same answer given by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams a little sooner , so marking his answer .